# How to alter the CartBlock build result?

Tags: commerce

I'd like to alter the cart block links (replace Cart link by a checkout link).

CartBlock.php is a BlockBase but neither hook_block_build_alter nor hook_block_view_alter is called :-(
(same result with a specific block hook like hook_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter or hook_block_build_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter with id "commerce_cart" )

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.api.php/funct...

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php...

Do I have to use a views hook ? which one ? and how to access to the block render array to change the links at the bottom of the cart block ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is the best way to do it but I successed using hook

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x

```
YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_block(&$variables)
```

==> to identify the block :

```
$variables["elements"]["#configuration"]["id"] == "commerce_cart"
```

==> to change the links with customs :

```
$variables['content']['#links']=$custom_links;
```